# Pointwise limit of the indicator function: $\lim_{c \to \infty}1_{\{X<kc\}}$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, characteristic-functions

I want to find the pointwise limit of this indicator function:

$$\lim_{c \to \infty}1_{\{X<kc\}}$$ 
where $k>0$ is a parameter and $1$ is an indicator function and $X$ is finite random variable.

---

One of my friends says it would be $\lim_{c \to \infty}1_{\{X<kc\}}=1_{\{x<\infty\}}=1$. Please provide me correct answer with explanation. Thank you.

Comment: Is this a pointwise limit, pointwise a.s., or some other notion?

Comment: yes pointwise limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $t$ in the domain of $X$, take $M$ so that $M>\frac{X(t)}{k}$. This is possible because $X$ is finite and $k$ is fixed. Then, for all $c\geq M$, we have
$1_{X<kc}(t) = 1$ because $X(t)<Mk\leq ck$. Therefore $\lim_{c\to\infty}1_{X<kc}(t)=1$ for each $t$, which means the pointwise limit $\lim_{c\to\infty}1_{\{X<kc\}}$ is $1$.

Answer (score -1):

$$\lim 1_{A_n} = 1_{\lim A_n}$$

So, convince yourself that $$\lim_{c \to \infty} \{X < kc\} = \{X < \infty\}$$ for $k>0$